# Why $P(aX+bY=c)=1\implies |\rho(X,Y)|=1$?

Tags: probability, random-variables

This is a lemma from Grimmet's book, from the chapter on Discrete Random Variables:
The correlation coefficient $\rho$ satisfies $|\rho(X,Y)|\le 1$ with equality if and only if
$P(aX+bY=c)=1$ for some $a,b,c\in \mathbb{R}$.

I understand the only if part, but I am not sure about the if part. Just any $a,b,c$ is enough?
The equality case of Cauchy-Schwarz is when $E((aX-bY)^2)=0\iff P(aX-bY=0)=1$. Now when I replace $X,Y$ by $X-E(X),Y-E(Y)$ respectively, we should get $P(aX-bY=aE(X)+bE(Y))=1$. From this, it looks to me that there is a relation between $a,b,c$, they just can not be any real.

What am I missing? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the function $\phi$ defined by
$$
\phi(t) = E\{\left[ (X - \mu_X) t + (Y - \mu_Y) \right]^2\}
$$

A simple calculation gives
$$
\phi(t) = t^2 \sigma_X^2 + 2 t \mbox{Cov}(X, Y) + \sigma_Y^2
$$

Since  $\phi(t) \geq 0$ and it is a quadratic function
of the form $A t^2 + B t + C$, we must have
$$
B^2 - 4 A C \leq 0  
$$
or
$$
\left[ 2 \mbox{Cov}(X, Y) \right]^2 - 4 \sigma_X^2 \sigma_Y^2 \leq 0
$$
which is equivalent to
$$
|\mbox{Cov}(X, Y) | \leq \sigma_X \sigma_Y
$$
or
$$
-\sigma_X \sigma_Y \leq \mbox{Cov}(X, Y) \leq \sigma_X \sigma_Y
$$

In other words
$$
-1 \leq \rho_{XY} \leq 1
$$

Also, we see that
$$
| \rho_{XY} | = 1
$$
if and only if the discriminant $B^2 - 4 A C = 0$ or that
the quadratic $\psi(t)$ has a single root.

Since
$$
\left[ (X - \mu_X) t + (Y - \mu_Y) \right]^2 \geq 0,
$$
we see that
$$
\psi(t) = 0
$$
if and only if
$$
P[(X - \mu_X) t + (Y - \mu_Y) = 0] = 1
$$

Thus, $| \rho_{XY} | = 1$ if and only if
$$
P(Y = a X + b) = 1
$$
with $a = -t$ and $b = \mu_X t + \mu_Y$, where $t$ is a root of  $\psi(t)$. Using the quadratic formula, we find that
$$
t = - {\mbox{Cov}(X, Y) \over \sigma_X^2}
$$